# help me decipher "z-index: 2e+09"

Tags: css, z-index

Inspecting the Typekit 'badge' (a fixed-position 'bug' used to promote that service on their free plan) I came across the following:

```
z-index: 2e+09
```

I'm puzzled by that value - can anyone help me decipher it? Thanks

edit: [link to example](http://www.lesleypalfreyman.com/typekit_sample.html)

Comment: lol so many answers already, anyway just to give you an idea why it is 2e+09 and not 3e+09 or a higher number is because the maximum value you can set for the z-index is 2,147,483,647 (as of the latest browser versions)

Comment: IOW signed 32-bit integer maximum. What's interesting is that this is still the case on 64-bit browsers. Here's an interesting read: http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2e+09` is a notation for 2x10<sup>9</sup> (known as [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)), or 2,000,000,000. It is actually from [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/types.html) (as well as [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Number)), and not technically valid in [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#numbers), <del>but most browsers implement it anyhow, as in all other cases, SVG and CSS numbers match, and they would rather maintain only one parser for numbers, not two.</del>

Actually, after checking, I was wrong; the browsers I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera) appear to ignore values set using scientific notation in CSS. So, this actually does nothing at all (it is treated as if `z-index` were not set at all, for a default `z-index` of 0), but the intent was probably to position the bug over all other content on the page. There is currently [some debate](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Aug/thread.html#msg473) on the CSS standardization mailing list as to whether e-notation should be allowed in CSS; it was mentioned in the discussion that some browsers already support it, but the ones that I tried did not appear to.

You can test for support with the following test case. If scientific notation is supported, then the green `div` should be on top; if it's not supported, thus defaulting to `z-index: 0`, it will be on the bottom, and if it parses just the mantissa and not the exponent (which I could imagine certain buggy browsers doing), it would be in the middle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Scientific notation test</title>
<style>div { width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; }</style>
<div style="background: red; left: 0px; z-index: 1;"></div>
<div style="background: green; left: 25px; z-index: 2e+09;"></div>
<div style="background: blue; left: 50px; z-index: 2;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`2e+09` is scientific notation for a very high number; a 2, followed by 9 0's (2,000,000,000)

Read [more about Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Answer (score 2):

`2e+09` is an exponential notation.  It means 2 times ten to the ninth power, or 2000000000.  They are trying to set the z-index as high as possible.

Answer (score 0):

2,000,000,000 or two billion, which is also 2 X 10^9 as that is scientific notation there.

Answer (score 0):

It basically mean a very large value (2,000,000,000). The designer probably wrote this to ensure that nothing get drawn over that element.